# Learning Magento from reviewing the core files

Tags: debugging, code, code-analysis

Prior to using Magento I had only used procedural programming techniques (and the code I wrote was very rarely reusable), although I was aware of oo, I had never had the need to use it, let alone  use something on the scale of Magento. So I would say my learning curve has been steeper than most but now due to my lack experience in oop I have found that I have come to a bit of a standstill.

I have learnt where I should place code, how to call models, blocks etc and with the help of [this book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Objects-Patterns-Practice-Experts-Source/dp/143022925X) I have been able to get a grasp of oop and through the help of [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) and [magento.stackexchange](http://magento.stackexchange.com) I have created a couple of my own modules. Everything I have learnt has come via the aid of google searches, but I do keep seeing repeating advice, which I am trying to now implement that advice is "LOOK AT THE CODE, IT HAS YOUR ANSWERS". But my problem is :

How do I look at something as abstract as the code in Magento and work out what it is going to be outputted on the screen? (when I've made my modules I've tried to avoid hard coding anything, but what i created somehow doesn't seem as abstract as whats going on in the core).

**An example of what i've tried to do and my thought process (in the hope i'm not over complicating this question).**

I have chosen to focus on finding out how a catalog items are generated when a specific category has been clicked e.g. `Home / Furniture / Bedroom`

with template hints on I can see that part of the page is generated from default/template/category/view

1. `default/template/category/view` calls `$this->getProductListHtml()` in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View`
2. `$this->getProductListHtml()` returns `$this->getChildHtml('product_list')` in `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract`
3. `$this->getChildHtml('product_list')` returns `$this->_getChildHtml($name, $useCache)` (I assume as 'product_list' was passed in earlier)

that is where I get lost. I've looked at `_getChildHtml` and am left wondering what is returned. How would I know if `$this->_childrenHtmlCache[$name]` is set? I assume that 'product_list' being passed in earlier would make it set. If that is the case the way I have read the code still leaves me with abstract terms that still don't mean anything or go anywhere (I expect there is more to review before I get to the end of a specific call).

I expected to start to see things link up for example `$this->getProductListHtml()` appears to be responsible for generating

- view as
- sort by
- [number] items
- image
- heading
- etc

but I have not found myself being led to even one of those things being called from the database (which was ultimately what I was expecting to find), what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You picked a bloody confusing place to start learning OO in Magento :-)

Comment: I agree, but I've gone to far to go back now :D

Comment: The page block structure is mostly defined via xml layout updates. In this particular case you will find it in /app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">. Good luck in your learnings - I hope someone can chime in with a more thorough explanation.

Comment: One further recommendation: Consider getting commerce bug by Alan which gives you a nice view of the different elements that make up a page.

Comment: @Fooman thanks for the suggestion. I do have commerce bug and found it a great help so far. I just need to find a way to manually dig through the code now as I don't want to rely on Google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find something accessing a class member, you search for where in that class the property can get set. This normally leads you to either a constructor or a setter. If it's the setter, you then have to start searching the code for calls to that setter. This becomes easier as you get more experience as you tend to get a gist of the general areas you need to look in and which search results you can ignore.

You rinse and repeat this process until you find the bit of information that you require. Be prepared to get 10 levels deep only to find you've forgotten what you were ultimately searching for. Another frustrating one is that you will get x levels deep only discover that the function you end up doesn't do anything except `return false;` or `return $this;` which can be extremely frustrating!

Comment: So coming across `return false;`and/or forgetting what your looking for is normal then, glad it's not just me. Ive started writing down the function I'm checking and each function that is being called to try and create a physical (kind of) map, but I'm still not getting to far

Comment: Using and IDE like PhpStorm can really help. It has buttons to step backwards and forwards through what you've been clicking on, so if you forget what you were looking for you can jump back until you remember and then continue.

Comment: Thanks, I've been using netbeans and just tried that and it works on Netbeans too, thanks